# Unable to reference PCL Project in Unit Test Project in VS2019 - Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, xamarin.forms, .net-standard-2.1

[image: Incompatible Target Framwork]

How do I fix this issue ? Unable to add PCL reference to my Unit Test Proj.

PCL proj is using framework NetStandardLib v2.1

Comment: what framework is the NUnit project?

Comment: Yes NUnit Project

Comment: which **.NET Framework** is the NUnit Project targeting?

Comment: <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>

Comment: try using `.NET Core`

Comment: How do I change the Target Framework from ".Net Framework 4.7.2" to ".Net Core" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245204/discussion-between-mainakchoudhury-and-jason).

Comment: Use the project properties.  If you are a .NET Developer you should really understand the basic features of Visual Studio.

Comment: Project Properties show various versions of .NetFramwork

Answer (score 1):

Testing this, NUnit Test project doesn't let you switch between Framework and Core once you have created it. Perhaps because different PackageReferences are needed.

Safest fix is to create a new NUnit Test project. But this time, when it asks for target Framework, pick a .Net core one. Probably pick the highest number it offers (Core 3.1).

Then copy or move all your test source files into it.

---

Looking at a Framework Test Project vs a Core one, these are the lines that are different.
Framework:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
...
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.16.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0"/>
  </ItemGroup>
...
```

Core:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
...
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit.Analyzers" Version="3.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
...
```